# Custom Admin Menu Items -sub items and --sub sub items

Tags: php, wordpress

We are trying to create in WordPress custom admin menu that has sub menu and each sub menu item will have submenu under it.

```
example:
Content
  .create CPT
       ..item 1 
       ..item 2
       ..item 3
  .use Blocks
       ..item 1
       ..item 2
       ..item 3
  .get discounts
       ..item 1
       ..item 2
       ..item 3
```

The below code works for creating the top level menu and the submenu when we add it in function.php in theme files but we don't know how to create a sub sub menu under the sub menu items

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'admin_menu_add_external_links_as_submenu');
add_action( 'admin_head', 'admin_menu_add_external_links_as_submenu_jquery' );

function admin_menu_add_external_links_as_submenu() {
    global $submenu;

    $menu_slug = "externallink"; // used as "key" in menus
    $menu_pos = 2; // whatever position you want your menu to appear

    // create the top level menu
    add_menu_page( 'external_link', 'Content', 'read', $menu_slug, '', '', $menu_pos);

    // add the external links to the slug you used when adding the top level menu
    $submenu[$menu_slug][] = array('<div id="newtab1">...create CPT</div>', 'manage_options', 'https://wpsimplehacks.com/how-to-create-custom-post-type-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin-within-couple-of-minutes/');
    $submenu[$menu_slug][] = array('<div id="newtab2">...use Blocks</div>', 'manage_options', 'https://wpsimplehacks.com/how-to-use-blocksy-content-blocks-hooks-full-tutorial/'); 
    $submenu[$menu_slug][] = array('<div id="newtab3">...get discounts</div>', 'manage_options', 'https://wpsimplehacks.com/start-here/'); 

function admin_menu_add_external_links_as_submenu_jquery() 
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {   
            $('#newtab1').parent().attr('target','_blank');
            $('#newtab2').parent().attr('target','_blank');  
        $('#newtab3').parent().attr('target','_blank');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
}
```

Any Help will be apprciated.